# Property of the trace and expectation

Tags: signal-detection, matrix, mimo, probability

I'm reading the paper *Model-Driven Deep Learning for Joint MIMO Channel Estimation and Signal Detection* by Hengtao He, Chao-Kai Wen, Shi Jin, and Geoffrey Ye Li on Orthogonal Approximate Message Passing (OAMP) detectors.

There is an step that it is getting me crazy, in Equation $(42)$ in Appendix B. It is the following:

[image]

At first, I thought that it was a consequence of a Hypothesis, but then, to derive the next expression in Equation $(44)$, it is used again this formula.

[image]

Is there some kind of property which I might be missing?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure which part you didn't understand. I'm assuming it's the step that goes from the rightmost expression at the top to the one at the bottom.
Assuming $\mathbf{q} = \mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}}$ is i.i.d.
Let me give it a try...

$
\begin{aligned}
\textrm{E}[ (\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}})^{\mathrm{H}}  \mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{H} (\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}}) ] 
& = \textrm{tr} \{ \textrm{E}[ (\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}})^{\mathrm{H}}  \mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{H} (\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}}) ] \} \\
& =  \textrm{E}[ \textrm{tr} \{(\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}})^{\mathrm{H}}  \mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{H} (\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}}) \} ]  \\
& =  \textrm{E}[ \textrm{tr} \{\mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{H} (\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}}) (\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}})^{\mathrm{H}}  \} ]  \\
& =   \textrm{tr} \{\mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{H} ~\textrm{E}[ (\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}}) (\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}})^{\mathrm{H}} ] \}   \\
& =   \textrm{tr} \{\mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{H} ~\textrm{E}[ (\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}}) (\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}})^{\mathrm{H}} ] \}   \\
& =   \textrm{tr} \{\mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{H} ~\sigma_{q}\mathbf{I}] \} \\
& =   \sigma_{q} \textrm{tr} \{\mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{H}] \}.
\end{aligned}$

where I am assuming $\sigma_{q} = \textrm{E}[  \|(\mathbf{x} - \hat{\mathbf{x}}) \|^2 ] = \frac{\textrm{E}[  \|\mathbf{q} \|^2 ]}{N_t} $.

As you can see, I am making a lot of assumptions here. I don't know if they hold since I couldn't access the paper. But I think it can shed some light on your problem (if your question is strictly about the trace operations).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was so focus in the techincality and formulas that I was missing the i.i.d hypothesis. Thanks!